# How to split numpy array wherever elements change

Tags: python, numpy

How can you split a numpy array of any datatype wherever the sequence changes. Examples of Inputs and desired outputs below:

```
# Inputs
a = np.array([1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,9])
b = np.array(["a","b","c","c","c","d","d","e","f","g","g","h","h","i"])
# Desired outputs
a:
[[1], [2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4], [5], [6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9]]
b:
[['a'],['b'],['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],['d', 'd'],['e'],['f'],['g', 'g'],['h', 'h'],['i']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your output consists of lists that are not equal sized, it can't be fully functional numpy array. Then you need to use Python tricks:

```
from itertools import groupby
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(a)]
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(b)]
```

If speed matters as well, use `a=a.tolist()` and `b=b.tolist()` before grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example way how todo it:

```
def consecutive_split(data: np.ndarray):
    b = np.roll(data,1)    
    return np.split(data,np.where((data!=b)[1:])[0]+1)
```